# React: Child Component Filtering Parent Component Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm confused why this isn't working.  I can do an API fetch, and filter the data just fine.  But, the parent component already has fetched this data, so I need to use it without doing another call.

Parent Component:(I want to filter the data set in `contacts` in a child of this component)

```
class Database extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                clients: [],
                contacts: []
            }
        }
```

I pass the `contacts` array of objects to the child component like so:

```
<Container className="database">
   {this.state.clients.map(client => (
     <ClientCard
        key={client.id}
        short={client.short}
        client={client.client}
        {...this.state}
      />
    ))}
 </Container>
```

Then in my child component, I am filtering the `contacts` data for use in my child component, so I have a beginning state of:

```
class ClientCard extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showHide: false,
            filteredContacts: []
        }
```

So what I would like to do now, is upon `componentDidMount`, filter the props data like so:

```
this.setState({
    filteredContacts: this.props.contacts.filter(contact => this.props.contacts.short === this.props.short)
     });
```

I'm not getting any errors, but it's also not setting the state of `filteredContacts` as needed either. The `short` mentioned in the code is an abbreviation for the clients stored in the array as an object property I'm using to help me filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `contact` passed down to the filter function in order to filter the contacts in that array. Presumably each `contact` holds a `short` property to which you want to compare it against the prop `short` of the component.

```
this.setState({
    filteredContacts: this.props.contacts.filter(contact => contact.short === this.props.short)
});
```

There shouldn't be a `this.props.contacts.short` since `this.props.contacts` is an array.